# Android always get a new location at the opening

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

As always get new location? I am using this code in `onCreate` here

```
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
               if (isGPSEnabled) {
                      if (location == null) {
                          provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 500, 0, this);
                          if (locationManager != null) {
                              location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);                                                    
                              if (location != null) {
                                  latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());                                   
                                  if (location != null) {                                                                                                             
                                      ParseQueryMap();
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                       }
                     }                            
              if (isNetworkEnabled){ 
                       if (location == null) {
                       provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 500, 0, this);
                       if (locationManager != null) {                   
                           location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);       
                           if (location != null) {
                               latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());                               
                               if (location != null) {  
                                   ParseQueryMap();                               
                               }
                            }
                         }
                       }
                     }
                }
```

If the location is not available when I run the application takes the previously known location (`getLastKnownLocation()`). I do not like this solution. I need to the application immediately or after a time (about 5 seconds) showed me my exact location. The exact location on startup I need to show the nearest point of the base. Is it possible? Thank you for any help

Comment: If the user has disabled GPS, you will not get an exact position. If the user has GPS enabled, you will receive a position "from network", if you choose that provider, which will be not that far away. Android itself, if configured to do so, refreshes the "last known location" on a regular basis, so it will not be that much off. For an exact position, you need to get a GPS fix, which can take (depending on the device and connectivity) a couple of seconds (even more than five). Other possibility: Run a service in background to refresh position every x seconds/minutes. Drains much battery.

Comment: @damian -What I would recommend to do in this situation? I want the user to open an application, see the nearest point and went to her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Passive Location Provider. By using it, you can receive location updates alongside other apps that have already requested them.

See [this blog entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) which describes in details how to fix the location as quick as possible. You may find the sample code in [android-protips-location](https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/) project.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but there is also the last known location in paragraph "Freshness means never having to wait". Or something I do not understand?

Comment: In exact, there is no way to get the current location with no delay, unfortunately. It's a technical limitation of GPS/Wi-Fi positioning, not Android. We have to wait for GPS fix or collect Wi-Fi signals around the device and ask to the location server. So, I guess all we can do is implementing the code described in the link above.

Comment: @Chernoff20 Try [Fused Location Provider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) in Google Play services API which introduced in [the latest Google I/O session](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325337477). In short, [LocationClient#getLastLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation()) should be nice for you.